# How to setup Cronjob For Magento in AWS (Ubuntu OS)?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, crontab, ubuntu, cronjobs

Recently i had moved my website from Bluehost to AWS.

Now i have to create cronjobs for magento in AWS (Ubuntu OS). please help me how to setup the cronjobs in Linux and if possible please share me the guide.

Comment: you have cpanel?

Comment: NO i dont have cpanel @Gohil Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You have to have SSH access to your Magento 2 installation in order to run it as smooth as it should. Make sure, you get the access.

As soon as you have access to your instance, go to the Magento 2 root directory and run `php bin/magento cron:install`  then put below 3 command

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

if you are on magento 2.4 then run only below single command other is deprecated

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Depending in the admin panel, you might have to enter the path to the PHP binary. If you are not sure which path it is, just try php.

in last run "crontal -l" for check your cron setuped or not

hope this helps you :)

Comment: you tried this?

Comment: for magento 2.4 it needs only one cron command `bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: @magenx it will run only once..they need like every 5 min

Comment: im saying from your list only first command required. others deprecated
`

Comment: exactly you are right. But they not clarified version.so, I posted all.

Comment: updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

go to AWS Console
select your instance
select `connect` from menu
choose your connection
after connection:

`cd` to magento webroot, and run as **magento files owner** `bin/magento cron:install`

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html